# Spring RestTemplate GET request does not give correct response

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

When I perform a get request with RestTemplate, the server's response is not the same as what I get via a curl or in my browser

I've tried playing with the URL encoding and logging the url to the console to further troubleshoot but can't explain the discrepancy.

```
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(URL + "search/all")
                .queryParam("keywords", UriUtils.encode(person, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .build(true);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriComponents.toUriString(), String.class);
```

The resultant `URL` from RestTemplate:
`https://example.com/api/v3/search/all?keywords=%C3%89tienne%20Racicot`
returns the response:
`{}`

Performing:
`curl https://example.com/api/v3/search/all?keywords=%C3%89tienne%20Racicot`
returns the response:
`{Person: {...} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by changing the logging level for the RestTemplate class to debug. Add `logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=DEBUG` to `application.properties` and you'll get a detailed log of the requests RestTemplate performs. This helped me notice that it was encoding the url I was passing a second time which I do not want. To avoid this pass `uriComponents.toUri()` to `restTemplate.getForEntity(..)` instead of a string.